# approaches to nearest neighbor searching

Tags: algorithm, nearest-neighbor

What kind of data structure should be used for nearest neighbor searching in 2d dimension?

I have searched and found out that there are many data structures for this: k-d tree, quadtree, octree.
So what kind of structure should I use?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944649/suitable-choice-of-data-structure-and-algorithm-for-fast-k-nearest-neighbor-sear?rq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15820226/nearest-neighbor-search-in-2d-using-a-grid-partitioning?rq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172358/all-k-nearest-neighbors-in-2d-c - did you research the existing answers?

Comment: That depends on your requirements. Try a few and see what works best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a [R-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree), it's designed for that purpose.

Comment: could you please clarify what kind of advantages its has over for example kd-tree.

Comment: Frankly, I haven't used the latter so I can't tell in detail, but this question came up earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326332/could-anyone-tell-me-whats-the-difference-between-kd-tree-and-r-tree